# Sharepoin, new Ribbon appears immediately after loading the page

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, ribbon

Good afternoon.  I am using Sharepoint 2019 on premise Classic view.  I need to create a new tab page using only Javascript as visual studio is not possible.  I made one code, it works, only a new tab appears only after selecting a file in the library.  and should be visible immediately.  how to do it?

Quellcode

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

  // Hauptfunktion, um den Ribbon-Tab zu erstellen und die SharePoint-Bibliotheken zu laden

  function initializeRibbon() {

    // Warten, bis die SharePoint-Bibliotheken geladen sind, und dann die Ribbon-Initialisierung durchführen

    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {

      // Zugriff auf die SharePoint Ribbon-PageManager-Instanz

      var pm = SP.Ribbon.PageManager.get_instance();

      // Wenn das Ribbon initialisiert wurde, rufen Sie die Funktion zum Erstellen des Tabs auf

      pm.CommandUIVisible = true;

      pm.add_ribbonInited(function () {

        var ribbon = pm.get_ribbon();

        createTab(ribbon);

ribbon.selectTabById(TAB_ID, true);

       

      });

      

      SP.Ribbon.PageManager.get_instance().get_commandDispatcher().executeCommand(Commands.CommandIds.ApplicationStateChanged, null);

    }, 'sp.ribbon.js');

  }

  // Konstanten für den Ribbon-Tab

  const TAB_ID = "Your.Tab.Id";

  const TAB_GROUP_ID = "Your.Tab.Group.Id";

  const TAB_TEXT = "Your Tab Text";

  const TAB_GROUP_TEXT = "Your Tab group text";

  // Funktion zum Erstellen des Ribbon-Tabs

  function createTab(ribbon) {

    // Tab erstellen und zum Ribbon hinzufügen

    var tab = new CUI.Tab(ribbon, TAB_ID, TAB_TEXT, "Tab Description", 'Tab.Attach.Command', false, '', null, null);

    ribbon.addChild(tab);

    

    // Gruppe erstellen und zum Tab hinzufügen

    var group = new CUI.Group(ribbon, TAB_GROUP_ID, TAB_GROUP_TEXT, "Group Description", 'Tab.Attach.Group.Command', null);

    tab.addChild(group);

    

    // Layout erstellen und zur Gruppe hinzufügen

    var layout = new CUI.Layout(ribbon, 'Tab.AttachNews.Layout', 'The Layout');

    group.addChild(layout);

    

    // Sektion erstellen und zum Layout hinzufügen

    var section = new CUI.Section(ribbon, 'Tab.AttachNews.Section', 2, 'Top'); //2==OneRow

    layout.addChild(section);

    

    // Erstelle die Buttons für die Sektion

    createButton(ribbon, section, group, TAB_ID, 'Tab.AttachNews.Button.Command', 'Tab.AttachNews.ControlProperties', 'o1', 'Google', '_layouts/15/images/discoveryExport_32x32.png', function () {

      openLink("https://www.google.de");

    });

    createButton(ribbon, section, group, TAB_ID, 'Tab.AttachNews.Button2.Command', 'Tab.AttachNews.ControlProperties2', 'o1', 'Bing', '_layouts/15/images/bing.png', function () {

      openLink("https://www.bing.de");

    });

  }

  // Funktion zum Erstellen der Buttons

  function createButton(ribbon, section, group, tabId, command, id, templateAlias, labelText, image32by32, onClickHandler) {

    // Eigenschaften für die Button-Komponente festlegen

    var controlProperties = new CUI.ControlProperties();

    controlProperties.Command = command;

    controlProperties.Id = id;

    controlProperties.TemplateAlias = templateAlias;

    controlProperties.ToolTipDescription = labelText;

    controlProperties.Image32by32 = image32by32;

    controlProperties.ToolTipTitle = labelText;

    controlProperties.LabelText = labelText;

    

    // Button erstellen

    var button = new CUI.Controls.Button(ribbon, id, controlProperties);

    // Button aktivieren

    

    // Button-Komponente für den Modus "Large" erstellen

    var controlComponent = button.createComponentForDisplayMode('Large');

    

    // Button zur Sektion hinzufügen

    var row1 = section.getRow(1);

    row1.addChild(controlComponent);

    

    // Layout für die Gruppe auswählen und den neuen Tab als ausgewählt markieren

    group.selectLayout('The Layout');

    SelectRibbonTab(tabId, true); //Mark new tab as selected

    

    // Button aktivieren

    controlComponent.set_enabled(true);

    // Klick-Eventhandler für den Button festlegen

    $(button.getDOMElementForDisplayMode("Large")).click(onClickHandler);

  }

  // Funktion zum Öffnen eines Links in einem neuen Browser-Tab

  function openLink(url) {

    window.open(url, "_blank");

  }

  // Aufruf der Funktion zum Laden der SharePoint JavaScript-Bibliotheken und zum Initialisieren des Ribbon-Tabs

  initializeRibbon();

</script>
```

I tried several options, nothing helped.  thank you in advance